# Third Party Controls License validation fails on Client Machine (.Net Windows Application)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have one Window based application developed in `.net 2.0 framework` and it uses some third party controls.
If i build setup of it and install on some client machines it is working without any issues but on one client machine it is showing Trial License expired of all third party controls, below are the system information.

**System Information**

Operating System: Windows XP Professional (5.1, Build 2600) Service Pack 2

Language: English (Regional Setting: English)

System Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard

```
   System Model: Presario R3200 (PR480UA#ABA)  
           BIOS: Ver 1.00PARTTBL
      Processor: AMD Athlon(tm) XP Processor 3000+,  MMX,  3DNow, ~1.6GHz
         Memory: 766MB RAM
      Page File: 284MB used, 1589MB available
    Windows Dir: C:\WINDOWS
DirectX Version: DirectX 9.0c (4.09.0000.0904)
```

I just formatted and re-installed OS on underlying Machine but no use same issue is retaining.

Comment: Did you read the documentation on the third-party controls about what you need to distribute them? (There's usually a `.lic` file associated with them that needs to be distributed.) Did you contact the vendor about support? You have given us no information about the third-party controls, so it's pretty difficult to provide a specific answer. The system information is meaningless.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and sorry about insufficient information. 
I am using IP*Works! SSL & Actipro UI studio third party controls also 
i am aware of the file which you specified (licenses.licx) but which was not shipped along with third party controls
anyhow if i add those controls in my project it automatically adds its license info in licenses.licx file 
which was created along with my winform project.
Reason which i have provided sys info is same setup is working on many client machines but such trouble occur only on one machine
so i could not be suspected my setup or third party controls